# consulta con case fecha menor que o mayor que

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo el siguiente *query*:

```
select Gage_ID,Description,Gage_Type,Location,Last_Calibration_Date,Next_Calibration_Date,Calibration_Frequency,
case  WHEN Next_Calibration_Date > GETDATE() THEN 'Requiere Calibracion'
      WHEN Next_Calibration_Date <= GETDATE() THEN 'Calibracion ok'    
   END,
GETDATE() as fecha 
from quality_v_gage
where Gage_Status <> 'Obsoleto/Perdido'
```

Donde estoy haciendo un `case` donde si la fecha es mayor a la fecha en la que estamos me indique que `requiere calibración` y si es menor la `calibración ok` 
pero no me esta respetando el caso.

Es decir, en las fechas de comparación me salen `calibración ok` cuando la fecha actual es mayor que la fecha de `Next_Calibration_Date`

ejemplo

```
Next_Calibration_Date = 12/31/2018 1:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: SQL server esta en mi erp que esta en la nube

Comment: Revisa que getdate() devuelva el valor en el mismo formato que Next_Calibration_Date... Y pon la etiqueta de sql server, así tu pregunta tendrá más alcance

Comment: @antonio, ¿si un registro tiene una `Next_Calibration_Date` pasada es cuando requiere calibración? Y si esa fecha está en el futuro es cuando `calibración OK`?

Comment: Solo pusiste al revés la comparación, quizás si comienzas a escribir la expresión desde el "GETDATE()" te des cuenta como escribirla bien. Somos todos humanos.

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona correctamente como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE quality_v_gage(
    Gage_ID int,
    Description varchar(100),
    Gage_Type int,
    Location int,
    Last_Calibration_Date datetime,
    Next_Calibration_Date datetime,
    Calibration_Frequency int,
    Gage_Status varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO quality_v_gage
VALUES( 1, 'Prueba 1', 1,1, '20180101', '20181231', 5, 'Activo'),
      ( 2, 'Prueba 2', 1,1, '20180101', '20191231', 5, 'Activo');

select Gage_ID,Description,Gage_Type,Location,Last_Calibration_Date,Next_Calibration_Date,Calibration_Frequency,
case  WHEN Next_Calibration_Date > GETDATE() THEN 'Requiere Calibracion'
      WHEN Next_Calibration_Date <= GETDATE() THEN 'Calibracion ok'    
   END,
GETDATE() as fecha 
from quality_v_gage
where Gage_Status <> 'Obsoleto/Perdido';
```

Revisa que los tipos de datos sean correctos.